# Questin and Answer extension with subscribe option

Tags: wordpress, joomla

My client required a question and answer component with following flow.

1. Admin can create a category for questions
2. Admin can create many number of questions and answers for a
       category.
3. Admin can set up payment integration to view the answer for a
       category. i.e to view all answers for a category then the user have
       to pay in our web site
4. In front end the user subscribed for a category then he can view all
       answers in the category.
5. If he want to view one more category answer then he needs to pay in
       our web site.

I am open for any paid version in Joomla or Wordpress in above functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: This is really not a question.

Comment: this is not place to post your requirement

Comment: Sorry guys.. I checked in the joomla extension forum and could not find suitable extensions, so thats why I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [EasyDiscuss](http://stackideas.com/easydiscuss) Joomla extension can be a good start here is a quote from the official website :

> "EasyDiscuss is a questions and answer extension that works like a
>   forum or a discussions portal for Joomla. EasyDiscuss includes
>   features that support social media sharing, optimized for search
>   engines, integrates with third party apps and lots more."

You can find a demo [here](http://demo.stackideas.com/forum.html)

If it does not fil all your needs you can still extend it's functionalities with plug-ins.

[Here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/question-a-answers) is some other extensions that may fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest best pair.

[Cobalt](http://www.mintjoomla.com/joomla-components/cobalt.html) - is the best CCK out there that will allow you to create Q&A section with a lot of other features.

[Emerald](http://www.mintjoomla.com/joomla-components/emerald8.html) - membership extension will allow users to subscribe to view certain answers.

Goot point that those are 2 extensions my one company www.mintjoomla.com and well integrated with eachother.